# ¿Cómo puedo traducir "pound" con algún verbo que signifique tanto "enfatizar" como "golpear"?

Tags: traducción, verbos, solicitud-de-término, humor

En inglés hay un refrán jurídico bastante famoso que hace referencia a ciertas artimañas legales de forma chistosa.

> If the facts are on your side, pound on the facts. If the law is on your side, pound on the law. If neither is on your side, pound on the table.

En español, eso quiere decir lo siguiente:

> Si los hechos están de tu lado, enfatízalos. Si la ley está de tu lado, enfatízala. Y si ninguno de los dos está de tu lado, golpea la mesa.

Se puede traducir sin problemas, pero se pierde el chiste porque la versión castellana no usa el mismo verbo para las tres oraciones. ¿Hay un verbo que se pueda utilizar en ambos casos, esto es, en todas las oraciones de la broma, aunque se emplee una acepción coloquial o arcaica?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se me ocurre [machacar](https://dle.rae.es/machacar?m=form).

> 1. tr. Golpear algo para deformarlo, aplastarlo o reducirlo a fragmentospequeños sin llegar a triturarlo.
>
> 2. tr. hacer polvo.
>
> 3. intr. Porfiar e insistir sobre algo.

"Si los hechos están de tu lado, machaca con los hechos. Si la ley está de tu lado, machaca con la ley. Y si ninguno de los dos está de tu lado, machaca la mesa."

Para los hechos y la ley estarías usando la acepción 3; para la pobre mesa, la 1 (bueno, o la 2, depende de cómo quede).

Comment: Con sentido similar, también serviría [atizar](https://dle.rae.es/atizar).

Comment: @aerobiomat Supongo que si, aunque por estos pagos no lo entendería nadie :D

Answer (score 5):

Tal vez no sea la mejor traducción, pero me ha hecho especial gracia:

> Si los hechos están de tu lado, haz hincapié en ellos. Si la ley está de tu lado, haz hincapié en ella. Y si ninguno de los dos está de tu lado, hinca el pie en la mesa.

De hecho, literalmente *[hincapié](https://dle.rae.es/hincapi%C3%A9)* significa "acción de [hincar](https://dle.rae.es/hincar) o afirmar el pie para sostenerse o para hacer fuerza", así que igualmente se puede decir "haz hincapié en la mesa", tendría un sentido más literal que figurado.

Answer (score 3):

Se me ocurre lo siguente:

*Si los hechos están de tu lado, combate con los hechos. Si la ley está de tu lado, combate con la ley. Si nada está de tu lado, combate con la pared.*

Obviamente, me tomé una pequeña licencia.